# WebSocket connection failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, socket.io, cloudflare

I am trying to setup WebSockets in my Javascript (React) application using [Socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io).

When using the `polling` transport from the Socket.io client (v1.4.5), everything works fine.
But I would like to use actual and secure WebSockets (`wss://` protocol)...

My server is a Debian 7 running Nginx v1.2.1 as a proxy for my virtual hosts, and my Node.js app (using Socket.io v1.4.5).

My domain name (api.tribeez.net) is set up via [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), which [just announced](https://blog.cloudflare.com/everybody-gets-websockets/) full WebSocket [support](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169466-Can-I-use-CloudFlare-with-WebSockets-) (including over SSL, i.e. `wss://`).

When I start my app in Chrome (v50.0), I see the WebSocket connection in the Network panel of Chrome (status `pending`).
But after one minute, the WebSocket disconnects (status `101 Switching Protocols`) and the console throws me a confusing `WebSocket connection to 'wss://api.tribeez.net/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&t=LI3t1dh' failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1`

When turning on socket.io debugging, this is what I get:

```
Fri, 06 May 2016 02:23:37 GMT socket.io:server incoming connection with id L43EOXmwsqkgCMVJAAAD
Fri, 06 May 2016 02:23:37 GMT socket.io:client connecting to namespace /
Fri, 06 May 2016 02:23:37 GMT socket.io:namespace adding socket to nsp /
Fri, 06 May 2016 02:23:37 GMT socket.io:socket socket connected - writing packet
Fri, 06 May 2016 02:23:37 GMT socket.io:socket joining room /#L43EOXmwsqkgCMVJAAAD
Fri, 06 May 2016 02:23:37 GMT socket.io:client writing packet {"type":0,"nsp":"/"}
Fri, 06 May 2016 02:23:37 GMT socket.io-parser encoding packet {"type":0,"nsp":"/"}
Fri, 06 May 2016 02:23:37 GMT socket.io-parser encoded {"type":0,"nsp":"/"} as 0
Transport=websocket, query=/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&t=LI3t1dh
Fri, 06 May 2016 02:23:37 GMT socket.io:socket joined room /#L43EOXmwsqkgCMVJAAAD
Fri, 06 May 2016 02:23:37 GMT socket.io:socket joining room tribe#1
Fri, 06 May 2016 02:23:37 GMT socket.io:socket joined room tribe#1
Fri, 06 May 2016 02:24:37 GMT socket.io:client client close with reason transport close
Fri, 06 May 2016 02:24:37 GMT socket.io:socket closing socket - reason transport close
```

And this is the Nginx log:

```
2016/05/06 04:24:37 [error] 28383#0: *549 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: api.tribeez.net, request: "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&t=LI3t1dh HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3010/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&t=LI3t1dh", host: "api.tribeez.net"
```

And my Nginx conf for this app:

```
http {
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }
}

server {
    server_name api.tribeez.net;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3010;
    }
    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3010;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Any idea why it closes? Could it be that I need to ping it regularly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer at the bottom of an [Nginx blogpost](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/): I needed to upgrade my Nginx version to a 1.3.13+. I installed the 1.10 (latest stable) using the right Nginx Debian repository ([see instructions](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html)), which fixed the issue.

Here is my browser output after setting `localStorage.debug = '*'`:

```
socket.io-client:url parse https://api.tribeez.net +0ms
socket.io-client new io instance for https://api.tribeez.net +5ms
socket.io-client:manager readyState closed +2ms
socket.io-client:manager opening https://api.tribeez.net +1ms
engine.io-client:socket creating transport "polling" +2ms
engine.io-client:polling polling +2ms
engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr poll +1ms
engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr open GET: https://api.tribeez.net/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LI4PaE9 +2ms
engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr data null +2ms
engine.io-client:socket setting transport polling +1ms
socket.io-client:manager connect attempt will timeout after 20000 +3ms
socket.io-client:manager readyState opening +3ms
engine.io-client:polling polling got data ArrayBuffer +468ms
engine.io-client:socket socket receive: type "open", data "{"sid":"0BCyhfQm--8uOQYUAAAb","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}" +5ms
engine.io-client:socket socket open +1ms
socket.io-client:manager open +0ms
socket.io-client:manager cleanup +1ms
socket.io-client:socket transport is open - connecting +0ms
engine.io-client:socket starting upgrade probes +1ms
engine.io-client:socket probing transport "websocket" +1ms
engine.io-client:socket creating transport "websocket" +0ms
engine.io-client:polling polling +2ms
engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr poll +0ms
engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr open GET: https://api.tribeez.net/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LI4PaLo&sid=0BCyhfQm--8uOQYUAAAb +1ms
engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr data null +0ms
engine.io-client:polling polling got data ArrayBuffer +252ms
engine.io-client:socket socket receive: type "message", data "0" +1ms
socket.io-parser decoded 0 as {"type":0,"nsp":"/"} +0ms
engine.io-client:polling polling +2ms
engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr poll +0ms
engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr open GET: https://api.tribeez.net/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LI4PaPo&sid=0BCyhfQm--8uOQYUAAAb +0ms
engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr data null +1ms
engine.io-client:socket probe transport "websocket" opened +441ms
engine.io-client:socket probe transport "websocket" pong +252ms
engine.io-client:socket pausing current transport "polling" +1ms
engine.io-client:polling we are currently polling - waiting to pause +1ms
engine.io-client:polling polling got data ArrayBuffer +98ms
engine.io-client:socket socket receive: type "noop", data "undefined" +1ms
engine.io-client:polling pre-pause polling complete +0ms
engine.io-client:polling paused +1ms
engine.io-client:socket changing transport and sending upgrade packet +0ms
engine.io-client:socket setting transport websocket +0ms
engine.io-client:socket clearing existing transport polling +1ms
engine.io-client:polling ignoring poll - transport state "paused" +0ms
```

Socket.io seems to be opening a polling connection anyway, but pauses it to prefer the websocket once the latter is working (I suppose...)

Comment: I'm facing your exact same problem but I dont have nginx. My socketio client is being served from my socketio server. Could it be different client/server versions...?

Comment: No idea... maybe post a new question with the details? I personally don't have enough knowledge to help you...

Comment: Oh dont worry I made another question and it was the antivirus. It was blocking websockets connections -_-