# Socket.io has stopped working since last 1 week

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, wss

Can anyone help me with this weird error that I'm facing since last week which is specific to windows 10 home edition (all browsers).  Its weird, as this error has arisen in a system which has been working fine since last 3 years (incl win 10 pc home/prof).

Error - "failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 0 " [ hence cannot connect to server ] ... however this works fine in a Windows 10 professional PC

Socket.IO Version - 0.9.16 ( wss://127.0.0.1:3000 ) ... behind NGINX with self-signed certificates
OS - Windows 10 Home Edition
Browser - Latest Chrome/Firefox
Node - v0.10.31

Comment: Hey, Im sorry I copied your text to create an issue on socketio github. I hope someone could give us some insight on this problem https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2543

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR

1. Update nginx.
2. Uninstall ESET NOD32 antivirus

---

**1) Nginx:**

See this if it helps:

[WebSocket connection failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063442/websocket-connection-failed-one-or-more-reserved-bits-are-on-reserved1-0-re)

> Found the answer at the bottom of an Nginx blogpost: I needed to
>   upgrade my Nginx version to a 1.3.13+. Installed the 1.10 (latest
>   stable) using the right Nginx Debian repository (see instructions),
>   and it seems to works fine now :)

---

**2) ESET NOD32**

Last week they updated their software putting more restriction on websockets connections.

Here is the eset nod32 thread which explains the problem:
https://forum.eset.com/topic/8355-protocol-filtering-breaks-websockets-after-update-at-5052016/
Refer to this github thread for more information about it:
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2543#issuecomment-218010922

Comment: Seems to me that you can close the `socket.io` issue that you created?

Comment: Ill change it to reflect my case, as I dont use nginx

Comment: Are you using wss and self-signed certificates perhaps?

Comment: nope, no wss. And Its a direct connection to the socketio server.

Comment: But using which protocol, "regular" websockets or secure websockets?

Comment: regular websockets

Comment: also tried updating nginx to latest .. but, it did not help solve the issue
uninstalling ESET solved the issue .. 
thank you